# Interactivity within the same graph - ggvis

Tags: r, graph, shiny, data-visualization, ggvis

I have the following ggvis with shiny code, which produces 2 graphs with the mtcars data set that comes with R. In the first graph if I double click on a point, all the points with the same number of gear (mtcars$gear) within the 2nd graph turns into red. Motor cars can have 3, 4 or 5 gears. So, if I click on a point in the 1st graph, which has 3 gears, all the cars which have 3 gears turn into red points in the 2nd graph.

This is the server.R code-

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$id <- seq_len(nrow(mtcars))


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  lb <- linked_brush(keys = mtcars$id, "red")

  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>%
    layer_points(fill := lb$fill, fill.brush := "red") %>%
    lb$input() %>%
    set_options(width = 300, height = 300) %>%
    bind_shiny("plot1") # Very important!

  # A subset of mtcars, of only the selected points
  selected <- lb$selected
  mtcars_selected <- reactive({
    mtcars[selected(), ]
  })

  mtcars_selected1 <- reactive({
    print(mtcars[mtcars$gear == mtcars[selected(), ]$gear, ])
  })

  vis <- reactive({ 
    mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>%
    layer_points()  %>%
    add_data(mtcars_selected1) %>%
    layer_points(fill := "#dd3333") %>%
    set_options(width = 300, height = 300)
  })

  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot2")
})
```

This is the ui.R code -

```
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  ggvisOutput("plot1"),
  ggvisOutput("plot2")
))
```

My question is, is it possible to do this in the same graph ? That is I want to click on a point and all the points with the same number of gears will turn into red in the same graph. I have googled it for a long time and I cant seem to find any direction. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make this example reproducible, so I can try it on my machine?  It seems there is some UI code missing.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I forgot about that. I have added both the server.R and the ui.R code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another layer in the first plot that will add the points that have the same gears as the selected points:

```
  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>%
    layer_points(fill := lb$fill, fill.brush := "red") %>%
    lb$input() %>%
    set_options(width = 300, height = 300) %>%
    #the next line will add red points that have the same gear as the ones selected
    layer_points(fill := "red", data = reactive(mtcars[mtcars$gear %in% mtcars[lb$selected(),]$gear,])) %>%
    bind_shiny("plot1") # Very important!
```

Comment: That is great, many thanks :). While I roughly understand what you did in the new inserted line, could you please let me know what was your thought process behind it ? Specially, as I am new with ggvis, I was mostly trying to work by looking at the official ggvis documentation. But there is no layer_points() function in there and I came to know about it from a ggvis tutorial. It is also confusing for me what arguments a function can take, as they seem very arbitrary.

Comment: I just figured it would be easier to add a layer of red on top of the points that have the same gears as the ones selected, thus the added `layer_points`. You can find examples of how they are used [here](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html). Here two arguments were needed, `fill` for the color and `data` for the data to be plotted. Data is in a `reactive` because it needs updating when `lb$selected` (the selected points) changes